# Javamail doesn't send a mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am developing a Java application and I am using Javamail to send a mail. My code is the following:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "diana.cartif.es");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("alerts","pass");
        }
    });

Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("alerts@cartif.es"));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("campus21@cartif.es"));
message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +"\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

Transport.send(message);
```

However when I execute this code it throws an Exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: diana.cartif.es, port: 465, response: -1
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1960)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.cartif.data.MainConnection.getFTPConnection(MainConnection.java:106)
    at com.cartif.main.Main.connectToServer(Main.java:72)
    at com.cartif.main.Main.main(Main.java:60)
```

Data to connect is right because I checked it in my Mail Server. Could someone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you resolve and ping that host from the machine where your application is running? Can you telnet to that host on port 465 and issue a HELO command?

Comment: Yes, it is working fine. I can ping and also connect via telnet. Of course I am receiving mails in Thunderbird, so that server is working.

Comment: You're using a wrong user/password or the user doesn´t have enough privileges to send emails as alerts@cartif.es. Maybe firewall issues.

Comment: @JoseHdez Are you under a proxy?

Comment: Can you really telnet to 465 and type in HELO? You shouldn't be able to because a SMTPS connection is encrypted so a telnet client shouldn't work. If you can telnet in, try running a EHLO command. If you see STARTTLS in the list then you need to be using props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve the problem with the following properties:

```
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smpt.host");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port","25");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "alerts");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
session.setDebug(true);

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mail1@mail.es"));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("mail2@mail.es"));
message.setSubject("Subject");
message.setText("Text");

Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
t.connect("user","pass");
t.sendMessage(message,message.getAllRecipients());
t.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe something like this:

```
     String  d_email = "email",
             d_password = "pass";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.server");
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", d_email);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

    Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the socketFactory* properties. In most cases they aren't needed anymore and add

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", true);
```

Try calling:

```
session.setDebug(true);
```

And see if you get anything helpful.

If you are using self-signed certs take a look at: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail145sslnotes-1562622.html